# Enabling a disabled button using Javascript in visual force negates its 'action'

Tags: visualforce, javascript

So I'm trying to enable the search button (default disabled) after a select option is selected other than --None-- using Javascript. It works totally fine except after the button becomes enabled, clicking it performs no action. Can anybody tell me why and how to enable it properly?

Heres the page block section of my visual force:

```
                <apex:pageblocksectionitem id="cpbsi">
                        <apex:outputlabel value="Select Category: " />
                    <apex:outputpanel >
                        <apex:selectlist id="sl" value="{!selectedCategory}" size="1" styleclass="inputStyle" onfocus="categoryFocus(), categoryColorFocus()" onchange="categoryColorFocus()" onblur="categoryBlur()">
                            <apex:selectoptions id="slv" value="{!categoryOptionsList}" />
                        </apex:selectlist>
                        <apex:outputlabel value=" " />
                        <apex:commandbutton id="search" value="Search" action="{!categorySearch}" rerender="products, errorSection, categories" styleclass="submitButtonStyle" disabled="true"/>
                    </apex:outputpanel>
                </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
```

Here's the Javascript that enables the button:

```
    <script>
    function categoryColorFocus() {
        var test = document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.pcpb.cpbs.cpbsi.sl}').value;
        if (test.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.pcpb.cpbs.cpbsi.sl}').style.cssText = "box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff6666; border: 1px solid #ff1a1a;";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.pcpb.cpbs.cpbsi.sl}').style.cssText = "box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00e600; border: 1px solid #00b300;";
            document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.pcpb.cpbs.cpbsi.search}').disabled = false;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Don't mind the styling code, just the lines that enable/ disable the button

Comment: `document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.pcpb.cpbs.cpbsi.search}').disabled = false` this is not working ? if not try with  just `console.log(document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.pcpb.cpbs.cpbsi.search}'));` and check the element you are getting or not

Comment: No that is working, its just once it enables the button, the button doesn't do what its supposed to do.

Comment: If i were to erase the disabled="true" in my visual force page, the button works, no I know there isn't anything wrong with the action

Comment: @tomshaep831 I tried also getting error. you can use html `<input type="button" value="save" onclick="ActionFunction()"/>` and try to enable or disable from your JS. And use actionfunction for calling your apex methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have used disable="true" and action="{!categorySearch}" directly in commandbutton and when it executes it replaces action with onclick="return false". Now when we enable the command button which is now input tag with type="submit" will have onclick="return false", so anyhow the action will not work.

Solution :
In javascript when enabling button, call an actionfunction using below code :

```
document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.pcpb.cpbs.cpbsi.search}').disabled = false;
categorySearchAction();

<apex:actionFunction name="categorySearchAction" action="{!categorySearch}" rerender="products, errorSection, categories>
```

Comment: No I didn't but if it doesn't work we should below one and it works
document.getElementById('{!$Component.FORMID.FIELDID}').disabled = false;

Also, we can have a look on below link for reference
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000095moIAA

Comment: Please check below link as a reference
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000095moIAA

If it is not supported then what is the use of disabled attribute in apex:commandbutton

I agree with the point that after disabling a actionbutton it doesn't call the controller method but for that we can call actionfunction, if we are using javascript.

Comment: After execution commandbutton becomes imput tag with submit type, so we can use below code easily for enabling that
document.getElementById('{!$Component.FORMID.FIELDID}').disabled = false;

Answer (score 2):

Looks like we can't enable or disabled the command button.

In place of command button create a `<input type="button" value="save" onclick="ActionFunction()"/>`

and in your javascript try to enable or disable this html input button.